# How to install Stripe components in Symfony 5?

Tags: symfony, composer-php, stripe-payments

As I have read in the Stripe documentation, I try to install this wonderful payment API in my Symfony 5 project using :

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

But I got the following error message :

```
env : php : No such file or directory
```

I have installed Composer locally and it was working weeks ago when I installed Symfony CLI...

I have found this solution on StackOverflow :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php71 /usr/bin/php
```

Then I got the error message :

```
Operation not permitted
```

I think there is something missing with my configurations ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: IF this worked a few weeks ago and doesn't anymore, you might need to re-install PHP first and then the Symfony CLI to start fresh

Comment: You got Operation not permitted when you created your symlink or after you created it when you tried to run composer again?

Comment: I got Operation not permitted when I created the symlink, before I tried to run Composer again

Comment: Well, that looks more like a Linux or Mac problem. I think it's kinda odd that you can't do it with `sudo`.

Maybe try doing `/usr/bin/php71 $(which composer) require stripe/stripe-php` as a work around. But that is very weird.